# How to write replaygain tags with album gain using mp3gain?

Tags: mp3, music

I installed mp3gain and looking at the manual it seems it is not possible to write replaygain tags while using album tags. BUT perhaps I missed something.

```
mp3gain optionally writes gain adjustments directly into the encoded data.
In  this  case, the  adjustment works with all mp3 players, i.e. no support for a special tag is required.
This mode is activated by any of the options -r, -a, -g, or -l.

   If none of the above options are given, the recommended gain change is instead written  to
   a  special  tag  in the mp3 file. In this case, the adjustment only works with mp3 players
   that support this tag.  Some mp3 players refer to this as ReplayGain.  The tag is  written
   either  in  APEv2  format  (default)  or in ID3v2 format (with -s i).  If you only want to
   print the recommended gain change (and not modify the file at all) you may use  the  -s  s
   (skip tag) option.
```

album tags is activate by using -a

Can you please help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The option `-a` of `mp3gain` does not mean "activate album tags" (whatever that is supposed to do). Look at `man mp3gain`:

> -a
>   apply Album gain automatically (files are all from  the  same
>   album: a single gain change is applied to all files, so their
>   loudness relative to each other remains  unchanged,  but  the
>   average album loudness is normalized)

In other words, `-a` causes it to calculate one and the same gain for all files it processes, modifying their gain in a uniform way. The idea is that all those files come from the same album, and hence should have the same relative loudness to each other after gain modification, but you can use this option also for files from different albums (or files that are not related in any way to albums). And it has absolutely **nothing** to do with the *album* tag.